# Java Singleton bean creating multiple instances of a list

Tags: java, singleton, javabeans

I am at a loss on what is going on here. I have a singleton bean that contains a list. When I add items to the list, the content is always consistent. However, when I call a get on that list from a different service, it returns an empty list with a different java id. Somehow the singleton bean has two different instances of the contained list based on who is calling.

Here is how the class is defined:

```
@Startup
@LocalBean
@DependsOn({ "classnameremoved" })
@Dependent
@Singleton
public class SomeManager
{
    private List<someType> aList = new ArrayList<someType>();

    public List<someType> getListData()
    {
         List<someType> returnList = new ArrayList<someType>();
         synchronized (aList)
         {
             returnList.addAll(aList);
         }

         return returnList;
    }

    public void handleCreatedEvent(Data someData)
    {
        synchronized (aList)
        {
             aList.add(someData);
        }
    }
}
```

The differences between the two are this:

The add method is called from a bean that listens for new messages and calls the appropriate handler. The get is called from another bean that handles the data after the fact. When I call from the two one after another, the list has a different ID and is not the same object. I can't figure out what this is happening.

In both beans I have the class above included with the following line:

```
@EJB
private SomeManager someManager;
```

The other two classes have the following annotations:

This class always has the proper data in the list and is not cleared over repeat tests.

```
@Singleton
@Startup
@LocalBean
@DependsOn("some class")
public class MessageListener ...
```

This class always get an empty list back

```
@Stateless
@LocalBean
@javax.ejb.TransactionManagement(javax.ejb.TransactionManagementType.BEAN)
public class GetClass ...
```

Any hints as to what is going on is much appreciated. This is all on a single local machine.

Comment: If there are any typos in the class names or annotations please ignore. This is not copied and pasted code as that is not something I can share. This is just a replica of how the classes are defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to see this resource.

> http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/singleton-1577166.html

Comment: From what I have been reading I am assuming my problem is "Multiple Singletons Simultaneously Loaded by Different Class Loaders". I just can't find any resources on how to resolve it so only one instance is being created.

Comment: I want to add here that singleton beans needs to be invoked in static context so that exactly one instance is created. I don't see that happening in your case.

Comment: Also there may be cases where multiple singleton can be loaded but the context has to be different

Comment: Is there any reference you could point me to for your first comment about static context? I am a C# developer thrown into a java world so my googling terms are throwing me off the correct path

Comment: btw I appreciate your assistance

Comment: Just found an article talking about the fact that the DependsOn annotation is what is causing multiple instances. I changed the lists to static and everything worked as I needed, but solving the root issue of multiple instances is more important. Trying to remove the DependsOn flag to see how that reacts.

Comment: Its good that dependsOn solves the issue but cruz of the matter is that always singleton are called from static context. Its mentioned in the same document.

Comment: That didn't fix it, but making the lists static did. So my takeaway is a java ejb singleton is not a singleton. C# take me back baby! :)  Thanks again user